# Simplest way to get a comprehensive listing of package names available in CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

Suppose that, as a private project, I have implemented a Perl package, and tested it, both formally and through extensive everyday use.  I find the package useful and solid enough to warrant submitting it to CPAN.

Up to this point, since the package has been a private project, I have not worried too much about the package's name, but now that I want to submitted to CPAN, however, I would like the package's name to fit well within the ecology of package names already in CPAN.

In order to find a suitable "CPAN name" for my package, I would have to inspect a comprehensive listing of all these package names<sup>1</sup>.

> What is the simplest way to get this comprehensive listing of names of packages in CPAN?

---

**ObPedantry**

(IOW, if the question above is already clear enough for you, you may safely ignore what follows.)

I don't think that I can give a technically correct formal definition of what I mean here by "package name", so let me at least give an "operational definition".

If, for example, the one-liner

```
$ perl -MFoo::Bar::Baz -c -e 1
```

fails with an error beginning with

```
Can't locate Foo/Bar/Baz.pm in @INC ...
```

..., but after installing some distributions from CPAN, the same oneliner succeeds with

```
-e syntax OK
```

...then I'll say that *"`Foo::Bar::Baz` is a package name in CPAN"*.

(We could split hairs over the package/module distinction, and consider scenarios in which the distinction matters, but please let's not.)

Furthermore, if after inspecting the list this question asks about I discover that, on the one hand, there are in fact many eminent package names in CPAN that begin with the prefix `Foo::Bar::`, and on the other, there are none (or negligibly few) that begin with the prefix `Fubar::`, then this would be a good enough reason for me to change the name of my `Fubar::Frobozz` package to `Foo::Bar::Frobozz` before submitting it to CPAN.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Of course, after inspecting such a list, I may discover that my package does not add sufficiently new functionality relative to what's already available in CPAN to warrant submitting my package to CPAN after all.</sup>

Comment: See [index of uploaded modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/01modules.index.html), [Perl5 registered modules list](http://www.cpan.org/modules/00modlist.long.html) and [On The Naming of Modules](https://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_namingmodules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have run `cpan` before, you have downloaded a comprehensive package and distribution list under `<cpan-home>/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz`.

A fresh copy is available on any CPAN mirror, e.g.
http://www.cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz .

Answer (score 4):

[PAUSE::Packages](https://metacpan.org/pod/PAUSE::Packages) can do what you want, however you probably want to use [this list](http://www.cpan.org/modules/01modules.index.html), but http://prepan.org/ can provide advice/review before submission to cpan, with of course reading [on the naming of modules](https://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_namingmodules) first.

Comment: `PAUSE::Packages` is enormous! It's not as bad as, say, `Moose`, but you could almost fill your time sheet for the day with *installing `PAUSE::Packages`*! Also note that the author **Neil Bowers** said *"NOTE: this is very much an alpha release"* back in October 2015.

Comment: installed in less than a minute here. Also, why not kick off module installs and check them when they're done, rather than 'fill your time sheet for the day' watching things happen?

Comment: it's not been updated since 2015, it's been in alpha for a while. Is it abandoned? Who knows. I provided a link to the data they need for easy access.

Comment: I was simply adding information. I didn't expect you to take it as a personal attack!

Comment: @Borodin I didn't, simply replied to your comment, and the edit

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that's a thing you want? There are 33,623 *distributions* on CPAN at the time of writing. Within `cpan` you can enter

```
cpan> d /./
```

That's `d` for *distributions* followed by a regex pattern that matches the names you're interested in

If you're really interested in *packages* -- and a distribution may contain multiple package names -- you need

```
cpan> m/./
```

where `m` is for *modules*. There are 163,136 of those, which means there's an average of four or five packages per distribution, and it takes `cpan` a few minutes to generate the list. (I'm sorry, I didn't monitor the exact time.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MetaCPAN::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/MetaCPAN::Client)

I found this [article](http://blogs.perl.org/users/neilb/2016/12/working-with-the-metacpan-api.html) which gives the idea about using this module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; use warnings; use MetaCPAN::Client;
my $mcpan  = MetaCPAN::Client->new();
my $release_results = $mcpan->release({ status => 'latest' } );
while ( my $release = $release_results->next ) {
    printf "%s v%s\n", $release->distribution, $release->version;
}
```

Currently this gave me **32601** result like this:

```
Proc-tored v0.11
Locale-Utils-PlaceholderBabelFish v0.004
Perinci-To-Doc v0.83
Mojolicious-Plugin-Qooxdoo v0.905
App-cdnget v0.05
Baal-Parser v0.01
Acme-DoOrDie v0.001
Net-Shadowsocks v0.9.0
MetaCPAN-Client v2.006000
```

This modules also gives information about **release, module, author, and file** & uses **Elasticsearch**.

It also get updated regularly on every MetaCPAN API change.